# Telegraf.js store text into user's input field

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm interested in is it possible to put some text into user's input field in telegram?

Like, you press some button or send a command and bot adds some text template into your input field.

Template example:

Project:
Priority:
Etc.

Comment: Yes it is possible . I cannot remember the function, but I have tested and worked

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this forum](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/705) with detailed explanation of how to use Telegraf scenes and stages, that should solve your issue.

TLDR: You can use WizardScenes to ask a series of questions for example. Here's sample code from the link provided:

```
import { Scenes } from 'telegraf';

const contactDataWizard = new Scenes.WizardScene(
  'CONTACT_DATA_WIZARD_SCENE_ID', // first argument is Scene_ID, same as for BaseScene
  (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('What is your name?');
    ctx.wizard.state.contactData = {};
    return ctx.wizard.next();
  },
  (ctx) => {
    // validation example
    if (ctx.message.text.length < 2) {
      ctx.reply('Please enter name for real');
      return; 
    }
    ctx.wizard.state.contactData.fio = ctx.message.text;
    ctx.reply('Enter your e-mail');
    return ctx.wizard.next();
  },
  async (ctx) => {
    ctx.wizard.state.contactData.email = ctx.message.text;
    ctx.reply('Thank you for your replies, we'll contact your soon');
    await mySendContactDataMomentBeforeErase(ctx.wizard.state.contactData);
    return ctx.scene.leave();
  },
);
```